# Extending a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $f: \mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ be the group homomorphism given by $f(a,b)=a-pb$ mod $p^2$. Now let $g: \mathbb{Z}_{p} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ be **any** group homomorphism. I want to show that there exists a group homomorphism $h: \mathbb{Z}_{p} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ such that $fh=g$.

**Question**: suppose now that we change (just) the domain of the map $g$ by $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$ where $n \geq 2$ and assume $g$ has no right-inverse. Can we still find such an $h$ (with the same definition of $f$)?

Comment: I think $h$ is not suitable; order of $[1]$ in domain of $h$ is $p$, but order of its image $(jp+p^3Z,0)$ is $p^2$, isn't it?

Comment: @Groups: thanks; I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show that every homomorphism $g:\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ factors through the homomorphism $k:\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ defined by $k([x])=[-px]$ (i.e there exists $\bar g: \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $k\bar g=g$). To do so note that $k$ is an isomorphism onto the kernel of $q:\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\to\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ defined by $q([x])=[px]$ and $qg([x])=[0]$. Then define $h([x])=([0],\bar g([x]))$.

Comment: @user10 Let $f:G\to H$ be a group homorphism and let $g$ be an element in $g$ of order $n$, then the order of $f(n)$ has be a factor of $n$ (because $f(g)^n=f(g^n)=f(1)=1$). But as Groups explained above the order of the image of $[1]$ by your homorphism $h$ has order $p^2$ while $[1]$ has order $[p]$ (when $j\neq 0$).

Comment: For example suppose $g([x])=[px]$, then $j=1$ and $h([1])=([p],[0])$ which has order $p^2$.

Comment: thanks; would this work? I'll omit the bars. Suppose that $g(1)=ip+p^2\mathbb{Z}$ where $1 \leq i \leq p-1$. Define $\overline{g}(1)=-i+p\mathbb{Z}$. Would the same construction work if we replace the domain of $g$ by $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ where $n \geq 2$?

Comment: @user10 Yes that is correct. Is the only thing you want to change the domain of $g$ i.e. you don't want to change $f$?

Comment: For $n>2$ there seems to be no problem solving the same problem. For $n=2$ I think it might not be possible.

Comment: For $n=2$. Let $u: \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$ and $v : \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \to \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ be arbitrary homomorphisms. We must have $u([1])=p[j]$ for some $1\leq j \leq p^2-1$ and so $p(f\langle u,v\rangle )([x])=p(pu([x])-pv([x]))=0$. This means that for any $h$ the order $fh([x])$ is a factor of $p$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32078/discussion-between-nex-and-user10).

Comment: I've updated the question now.